# How can I extract numbers using regex from the following patern : {"idProveedors":["73","3","67333"]} in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract numbers from the following string de number of digits can verry.

```
{"idProveedors":["63","63333","3"]}
```

Here is my inital code I tried many diffrent pattern but none seem to work

```
        string pattern = @"";

        Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

What pattern should I use to extract the digit I put them in a list of string in c# thank you for your help

Comment: This should get you the list of ints... `List<int> numbers = JObject.Parse(stringJson)["idProveedors"].ToObject<List<int>>();`

Comment: Thank you very much @Jawad it works it is exactly what I wanted.